# Generators and relations for $\text{PSL}(2, \mathbb{F}_q)$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

Is there a nice presentation for the group $\text{PSL}(2,\mathbb{F}_q)$, for every prime $q$?

(I don't have any particular definition in mind for "nice", other than, say, a small number of generators and relations.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $q$ is an odd prime then
$$
\langle x,y \mid x^q=y^q=(x^ay^b)^2=1, ab\equiv 1 \mod q \rangle
$$
is isomorphic to $PSL(2,q)$. An efficient presentation is given by
$$
\langle x,y \mid x^2=(xy)^3=1, (xy^4xy^{\frac{q+1}{2}})^2y^q=1\rangle,
$$
see Campbell papers.